# Can't get bind() to work

Tags: zend-framework2

I want my form fields to contain the previous data contained in database when the form page opens. I went through lots of queries here and came to know using populate() or bind() method is the way to do it. But when I try to use it, I get an undefined method error. 
Is there any other way to do it? 
I am unable to use bind() as well. I am getting a fresh form with default values after I submit.
Sorry if this is a stupid question. Its been only 4-5 days since I started learning Zend framework. Also, most of the methods I get online are for older frameworks. I am using Zend Framework2.

This is Controller Code

```
<?php
class ChatController extends AbstractActionController 
{
    protected $chatTable;

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $form = new ChatForm();
        $model= new Chat();
        $form->bind($model);
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Save');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $gen_set = new Chat();
            $form->setInputFilter($gen_set->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $gen_set->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                $this->getChatTable()->saveChat($gen_set);

                // Redirect to list of albums
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('chat');
            }
        }
        return array('form' => $form);
    }

    public function getChatTable()
    {
        if (!$this->chatTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->chatTable = $sm->get('Chat\Model\ChatTable');
        }
        return $this->chatTable;
    }
```

}

My Entity Class, Here api_key and anon_prefix are rows of the column 'settings' and there is one more column with value.

```
<?php
class Chat implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{

    protected $inputFilter;                         

    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->api_key=(isset($data['api_key'])) ? $data['api_key'] : null;
        $this->anon_prefix  = (isset($data['anon_prefix']))  ? $data['anon_prefix']  : null;    
    }


    // Add content to these methods:

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

     public function getInputFilter()
     {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'iflychat_external_api_key',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
            ));

            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'iflychat_show_admin_list',
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'    => 'InArray',
                        'options' => array(
                            'haystack' => array(1,2),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ));


            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }

    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

This is used to enter values into db

```
<?php
class ChatTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }


    public function saveChat(Chat $gen_set)
    {

        $data = array(                                      
            'value' => $gen_set->api_key,
        );
        $id='iflychat_external_api_key';
        $this->tableGateway->update($data,array('settings' => $id));

        $data = array(
            'value'  => $gen_set->anon_prefix,
        );
        $id='anon_prefix';
        $this->tableGateway->update($data,array('settings' => $id));
    }
}
```

I am getting this error, 'Cannot use object of type Chat\Model\Chat as array'

Comment: Check for `$form->bind($model);` in ZF2 to load data from the database (usually for edit actions). To populate the form with data posted after form-submit, do this - `$request = $this->getRequest(); if ($request->isPost()) { $form->setData($request->getPost()); }`

Comment: The `bind()` is very useful when then `$model` has lot of attributes. If you want to set the data manually then try this- `$form->get('id')->setValue($model->id);` where `id` is one of the field in the form.

Comment: @KunalDethe When I use bind, I get an error 'Cannot use object of type Chat\Model\Chat as array'

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj code added.

Comment: Add this use statement in your controller - `use Zend\Form\FormInterface;`. Then instead of `$gen_set->exchangeArray($form->getData());` write `$gen_set->exchangeArray($form->getData(FormInterface::VALUES_AS_ARRAY));` and try.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj Hey! That removed the errors. But problem remains the same. After submit, I get a fresh form with default values. I wanted the changed values to display on the form page.

Comment: Code written is - after `$this->getChatTable()->saveChat($gen_set);`, do redirect to `chat` route. i.e. its redirecting to the `indexAction` itself, which is suppose to display the empty form.

Comment: To just view the submitted values in the form, remove the `return $this->redirect()->toRoute('chat');` line and you will get it.

Comment: But if you like to always view the most recently saved chat in the form, you need to fetch it from database. Eg: `$model_previous = $this->getChatTable()->fetchLastChat();`, where unlike the `fetchAll` function in `ChatTable`, only fetch the last record. Let us know if you need help with that.

Comment: Yes. That is what exactly I wanted to do. Fetch value from value column based on setting id. If you can help with that, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Your action doesn't make much sense as it is, you instantiate a `Chat` instance as `$model` and later another instance as `$gen_set`. What you should be doing is binding the first one, and using the form class `getData` method to later return the instance you bound to it, along with the values you gave it in the `setData` method. There's no need for any transformations from object to array and back again.

Here's how it should look ...

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $form = new ChatForm();

    // bind the model
    $model= new Chat();
    $form->bind($model);

    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Save');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setInputFilter($gen_set->getInputFilter());

        // set data from POST as properties of the bound model ...
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            // get the bound model instance with the POSTed values
            // ($gen_set is now the original $model object instance bound above) 
            $gen_set = $form->getData(); 

            // and save it
            $this->getChatTable()->saveChat($gen_set);

            // Redirect to list of albums
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('chat');
        }
    }

    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

Comment: I did realise that I created 2 instances of chat after posting. But this still didn't help. As my form id and its value are stored in rows of 2 column, and what we are doing here extracts column values, I guess. :/

Answer (score 0):

Controller Code -

```
<?php

class ChatController extends AbstractActionController {

    protected $chatTable;

    public function indexAction() {

        $model = $this->getChatTable()->fetchLastChat();
        if($model === null || $model->count() == 0)
            $model = new Chat();

        //Now if no record exists in the database then $model will be empty
        //Else $model will contain data of last record.

        $form = new ChatForm();
        $form->bind($model);
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Save');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $gen_set = new Chat();
            $form->setInputFilter($gen_set->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $gen_set->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                $this->getChatTable()->saveChat($gen_set);
            }
        }
        return array('form' => $form);
    }

    public function getChatTable() {
        if (!$this->chatTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->chatTable = $sm->get('Chat\Model\ChatTable');
        }
        return $this->chatTable;
    }

}
```

ChatTable Class Code -

```
<?php

//Other use statements

use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

class ChatTable {

    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll() {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }

    public function fetchLastChat() {
        $select = new Select('TABLE_NAME'); //Change the tablename accordingly
        $select->order('PRIMARY_KEY DESC'); //Set the Primary Key of the table
        $select->limit(1);

        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        return $resultSet->current();
    }

    //Rest of the Code ....
```

Please take the idea from the above code.